# visual studio 2015 create text box or anything in microsoft word document

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, ms-word, office-interop

Is it possible to create a table/shape/text box in a Microsoft Office Word Document using VB in Visual Studio 2015?

All I can find online is to create a document/save it/close word.
I am trying to create a table given certain values a user will decide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found This example at MSDN. Dont forget to add a reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    CreateTableInWordDocument()
End Sub

Private Sub CreateTableInWordDocument()
    Dim objWord As Application
    Dim objDoc As Document
    Dim objTable As Table
    objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True
    objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
    Dim r As Integer, c As Integer

    objTable = objDoc.Tables.Add(objDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range, 3, 5)
    objTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6
    For r = 1 To 3
        For c = 1 To 5
            objTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = "Row" & r & " Coulmn" & c
        Next
    Next
    objTable.Rows.Item(1).Range.Font.Bold = True
    objTable.Rows.Item(1).Range.Font.Italic = True

End Sub
```